# Expected ArgumentError but got NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, arguments, block

When I call individual methods in the classes below, I was expecting `ArgumentError`, but I see:

```
class A
  def with_one_argument(&block)
    block.call
  end
end

A.new.with_one_argument
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
```

But this acts as expected:

```
class B
  def with_one_argument(some_value)
    puts some_value
  end
end

B.new.with_one_argument
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Can anybody explain why `(&block)` is treated as special? In my understanding, if I do not provide a default value to an argument then `ArgumentError` is expected.

Comment: thanks for edit @sawa, it looks more cleaner now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing complicated. The fact is simply that a block is not an argument. With `A`, if you pass a block, that would be referred to as `block` as a converted proc, otherwise `block` has the value `nil`. But in either case, `block` is the result of converting the passed block (which is neither an argument nor an object) to a proc (which is an object).

Comment: but the name `block` is given by me, I can put any name I like and use it that way. How come its not an argument? can you provide some reference links @Sawa